# How to figure the size of the following vector set?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ with entries $±1$. What is the size of this vector set?

I know the answer is $2^n$ but I cannot prove why. I feel like this has something to do with combinations or permutations but it is not as straightforward.

The way that I see this problem is as all the numbers in decimal that we can make given $n$ binary digits. So for example, it is clear that with $2$ binary digits we can represent up to $2^2 = 4$ numbers: $$00 = 0_{10} \\ 01 = 1_{10} \\ 10 = 2_{10} \\ 11 = 3_{10}$$

This is essentially the same problem as the one I have. However, I cannot find a formal proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

You are trying to define a bijective function $f$ from vectors to the set of vectors with coordinates $\pm 1$ to the set of integers $0 \leq n < 2^n$.

Since $f$ is bijective, that would show both sets have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ have entries $v_i = \pm1$.  How many choices are there for the value of $v_1$? For each such choice, how many ways can you choose the value of $v_2$? And so on.